# Magnitude of transfer function

Tags: signal-processing, dsp

[image]

I was able to find the transfer function of this LTI system block diagram, but am unsure of where to start on how to find the magnitude. The transfer function I have from this is:
$$H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = a - be^{-s\tau}$$

Every example I've seen takes each element separately and squares them like this, but this doesn't quite make sense to me:
$$|H(j\omega)| = \sqrt{a^2 - (be^{-s\tau})^2}$$

Comment: Visually, you have a vector, **a**, pointing to the right (no imaginary part) from which you are subtracting another vector with length equal to `b*exp(-sigma*tau)` and with an angle of `-omega*tau`. (Plus or minus on the angle won't/shouldn't matter to the result.) So the magnitude will be the square root of `[a-b*cos(-omega*tau)*exp(-sigma*tau)]^2+[b*sin(-omega*tau)*exp(-sigma*tau)]^2`. That's `sqrt[a^2-2*a*b*exp(-sigma*tau)*cos(omega*tau)+b^2*exp(-2*sigma*tau)]`. Note that cos(-a)=cos(a). This isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 0):

Your magnitude equation is not correct.

First you have to separate the H(jw) to real & imaginary parts and then, you can find the magnitude by squaring and adding the real and imaginary parts and then taking square root.

Hint: exp^(-jwT) = cos(wT) - j*sin(wT)
Use this and it will be easy to separate the real and imaginary terms in your transfer function